# Problem loading chartjs plugin using require.js

Tags: charts, knockout.js, requirejs

Is order to customize Chart.js evend more I want to add another library.
I'm having a hard time loading a library for Chart.js

the library is chartjs-plugin-datalabels. I'm using chart.js 2.8.0

This is my require.config.js file

```
var require = {
urlArgs: "v=10",
baseUrl: "/",
waitSeconds: 0,
paths: {
    "bootstrap": "Scripts/bootstrap",
    "jquery": "Scripts/jquery-3.3.1",
    "blockUI": "Scripts/jquery.blockUI",
    "knockout": "Scripts/knockout-3.5.0",
    "momentjs": "Scripts/moment.min", //needed by chart js
    "chart": "Scripts/Chart.min", //chart js
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "Scripts/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min", //chartjs plugin
    "dataTables": "Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min",
    "text": "Scripts/text",
    "sammy": "Scripts/sammy-0.7.5",
    "common": "App/common",
    "datepicker": "Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker",
    "datepickerITA": "Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it",
    "toastr": "Scripts/toastr",
    "api": "App/api",
    "settings": "App/settings"
},
shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "toastr": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "blockUI": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "dataTables": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "chart": {
        deps: ["momentjs"]
    },
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": {
        deps: ["chart"]
    },
    "sammy": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "common": {
        deps: ["knockout", "jquery"]
    },
    "datepicker": {
        deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap"]
    },
    "datepickerITA": {
        deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap", "datepicker"]
    },
    "api": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    }
}
```

This is the page configuration

```
define(["knockout", "text!./page-corso-progress.html", "toastr", "api", "common", "bootstrap", "chartjs-plugin-datalabels"], function (ko, pageTemplate, toastr, api, common, chart)
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm having the same problem